# Prevent browser blocking with the message "Too many redirect"

Tags: php, redirect

I am working on a PHP script which takes several minutes to execute because it is about downloading images.
I need to run this script on underperforming servers whose configuration or settings are not in control.

I was constantly stuck with a problem with the execution time limit.
So I found a trick of doing redirects within my script (passing a parameter) in order to separate each image into a new script execution.

It works very well on a performance level, however now I have errors in the browser judging that there is too much redirect.

My script may need to download several dozen images for each run. Several hundreds maybe.

Does anyone have a solution to this redirect problem?
If not, maybe there is another solution than redirects to run my script on poorly performing servers?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of redirecting you could use iframes or javascript.

Comment: You mean to do all the processing via ajax calls for example?
Return n°1 of the ajax, I launch the call n°2, return of the n°2, I launch the n°3 etc ..?

I chose the solution to do with redirects because I need my script to be able to be called from a CRON task or from the browser.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. I would run several conversions in parallel, that would speed up the process. Using iframes is somewhat simpler, but gives you less control, so I would definitely go with ajax. Ah, but you can't use Javascript when running a CRON task, nor iframes or redirects.

Comment: The fact that you want to use PHP from the command line is missing from your question.

Comment: Hi

Indeed it is an oversight on my part.

I will still try to set up the solution in Ajax for manual executions. This will stop the "TOO MANY REDIRECT" problems.

And CRON shouldn't be bothered by multiple redirects normally.

I'll keep you informed,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can disable any extensions in Chrome that could cause an err_too_many_redirects error. To do this, open Google Chrome and select the menu icon > More Tools > Extensions. In the Extensions menu, identify any extensions that you believe may cause this issue, such as VPN or ad blocking extension.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your reply.

Even when launching the script from a browser without any extension, the same message appears "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"